# How to automatically set the width of an HTML element to the width of the enclosed text

Tags: html, css

Here is an example:

[image]

I would like for the width of the h1 or a surrounding div to "clip" the text so that I can, for example, draw a border around only the text.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the header element an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) by giving it a `display` attribute of `inline` or `inline-block`:

```css
h1 {
  border: 3px dotted black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Alternatively, you can make the surrounding element have [`width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content), though note that this is **not** supported in Internet Explorer:

```css
.container {
  width: fit-content;
}

h1 {
  border: 3px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the element style to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

```css
.index-header {
    display: inline
}
```